# Countdown Clock

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to create a countdown clock that when  you show up on the page it starts to countdown from a pre-defined number, say 8 hours. If you leave the page, say after 2 hours, I would like it to stop counting down. If you return to the page I want it to resume counting down, now with only 6 hours left.

Is this possible using javascript client side, and php server side?

If I wanted to create multiple user generated countdowns can I use mySQL to store the different variables?

Obviously I have a lot to work out here, I don't want someone to write me the whole code. I am looking for a starting point, maybe some tutorials or advice on which way to start perusing. I am very much a novice at js, php, mysql but can work with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses [a countdown plugin for jQuery](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html). Download the [jQuery Countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/zip/jquery.countdown.package-1.5.9.zip), and place `jquery.countdown.css` and `jquery.countdown.min.js` in the same folder as your file (or elsewhere, and adjust the paths in the code below). In the head section of your document include this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">@import "jquery.countdown.css";</style>
```

Somewhere in the PHP code, before anything is outputted, run this to set when the time will be:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIES['endtime'])) {
    $endtime = time() + 28800000;
    setcookie('endtime', $endtime);
} else {
    $endtime = $_COOKIE['endtime'];
}
```

Then, where you want the timestamp to appear, output this HTML:

```
<span class="countdown hasCountdown" id="myCountdown"></span>
```

And somewhere after it, output this JavaScript:

```
var targetDate = new Date(<?php echo ($endtime ); ?>); 
$('#myCountdown').countdown({until: targetDate});
```

---

**EDIT**: Alright, here are some improvement on my previous answer to include pausing when the user leaves the page. I'm also switching the post over to community wiki so anyone is welcome to edit and improve it.

In order to track when the user was last on the page, you need to keep a cookie that you update every 5 seconds or so with the current time. Here's a bit of JavaScript that does just that:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays)
{
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function updateCookie()
{
    var curTime = new Date();
    setCookie('lastvisit', curTime.getTime(), 30);
    setTimeout("updateCookie()", 5000);
}
```

You need to run `updateCookie()` once and then it will keep running every five seconds. To have it run for the first time as soon as the page has finished on loading, add an onLoad to your body tag, like this:

```
<body onLoad="updateCookie()">
```

Your PHP code will then look like this instead of the one above:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIES['lastvisit']) || !isset($_COOKIES['endtime'])) {
    $endtime = (time()*1000) + 28800000;
    setcookie('endtime', $endtime, time() + 2592000);
} else {
    $prevendtime = $_COOKIE['endtime'];
    $lastvisit = $_COOKIE['lastvisit'];
    $timeleft = $prevendtime - $lastvisit;
    $endtime = (time()*1000) + $timeleft
}
```

All the cookies are set to expire after 30 days, so if your user stays away for more than 30 days they will reset.

Comment: That is not secure. It allows the user to freely change the countdown number, which could be trial time for some paid service. Which is hardly the result I would want on my script.

Comment: The asker hadn't specified that it should be secure, and since the purpose wasn't specified, I assumed that security wasn't necessary, so I went with the simplest situation and the only one that doesn't involve using server-side storage space. There's plenty of situations where it's okay for the user to be able to change it (for example, a countdown to the user's birthday, or a countdown to the release of a new product, etc.) and really not that many where security *is* needed.

Comment: Security would not really be needed, in fact letting the user change the number would be preferable.

Comment: Well, the server still has to be used as a reference point, since @EdoDodo 's code here won't count when the user has left (it will count for 8 hours regardless of the user's state in the site), what I suggest is a 10 seconds recurring AJAX call, to update the cookie (at least). Good luck.

Comment: I tried the above and got the following error:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (filelocationonserver/countdown.php:3) in /filelocationonserver/countdown.php on line 11

Comment: Are you sure you've placed tbe PHP code before *anything* else - including any new lines, or includes?

Comment: Okay I fixed that, no more PHP errors. Now I see that my targetDate is the following: Thu Jan 15 1970 22:41:25 GMT-0600 (CST)     I threw an alert because I was getting 0hours left in my clock. Why would it choose that time?

Comment: Ah, looks like PHP timestamps are expressed in seconds, whereas JavaScript's in milliseconds. I've adjusted the code accordingly, could you try it again?

Comment: Okay the code now successfully figures out the current time, adds 8 hours and starts counting down from a time that is 8 hours out. When I close the tab and then re-open it (using cntrl+shift+t) what happens is that it keeps counting down while I am away. When I reload the page or open up a new instance it just starts over from 8 hours out. See here: [link](http://angelajonescc.com/countdown/countdown.php) What I would like it to do is to keep counting down no-matter if the window gets closed or opened or refreshed.

Comment: Looks like I mis-spelled the `$_COOKIE` variable as `$_COOKIES`, could you try again with the new code where it's spelled `$_COOKIE`?

Comment: It is working to the extent of counting down for 8 hours from when you first visit the site. How would you set another cookie for time spent on the site so that you could track how long the timer should have left if you only want to countdown while on the site?

Answer (score 2):

Give the user a unique ID via a cookie, using [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), and then save the unique id and the time of the countdown on the server side (in a database or a file), then, once the user enters and his browser dilvers the cookie, figure out the unique ID, and give him the time needed for the countdown.

As for the countdown itself, there are plenty of plugins such as [this excellent plugin given](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) by the answerer above me. Pass the date to JavaScript's `Date` object via PHP, and use the plugin.

Comment: You could probably store the countdown start time in a client-side cookie via JavaScript too, if you didn’t want to bother storing IDs on the server-side.

Comment: You have to store the ID on the server side, otherwise how'd PHP make the connection between the ID the client gives to the the actual start time?

Comment: I was thinking that on page load, a) PHP outputs the current datetime somewhere in the HTML of the web page, b) JavaScript checks for a cookie called e.g. `countdown_started_at`, and c) if the cookie doesn’t exist, JavaScript sets the cookie to the current datetime and starts the countdown from the predefined number, or d) if the cookie exists, JavaScript restarts the countdown from the value returned by subtracting `countdown_started_at` from the current datetime.

Comment: Doable, but if security is a concern, you'll need to use the ID. Although you're solution is great if no security needed.

Comment: So PHP doesn’t track the start time at all. JavaScript does. You wouldn’t necessarily want to do it this way, but it does cut out the need for a database. I think it’s the simplest way to implement the functionality as described by Crisman. (Of course, in the grand tradition of clients, he may not have told us all the details.)

Comment: True, but the server must still be used as a reference point, to update the cookie and to set a standard timing structure.

Comment: totally, otherwise you’re stuck with the end user’s clock. For an 8-hour countdown, that might even be reasonable, but for want of a PHP `time()` call, why not.

Comment: Okay I have been reading through this answer and I cannot figure out how you would keep track of how long the timer has run using either the unique ID suggested or the countdown_started_At cookie. I have the code from the above answer working to the extent of counting down a total of 8 hours from when you visit the page, with a session cookie that tracks when you want the timer to end. I think what I am missing is a cookie or variable to track how long the page was open.

Comment: @Crisman, you need 2 things in your cookie, the time the countdown was started on, and the current time, which is updated frequently. Once the user leaves the site, the cookie stops updating. So when the user returns, the remainder time can be calculated and restarted.